# Why can't I get JQuery AJAX call to work unless URL and success functions are hardcoded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have several PHP scripts that I want to use so I am trying to create a generic PHP call function.  Here is what I have so far ...

```
function CallPHP(script, handler) {
  $.ajax({
    type:      'GET',
    url:       script,
    data_type: 'json',
    success:   handler,
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      var msg = '';
      if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
          msg = 'Not connected.\n Verify Network.';
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
          msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
          msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
      } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
          msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
      } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
          msg = 'Time out error.';
      } else if (exception === 'abort') {
          msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
      } else {
          msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
      }
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

I am calling it as follows ...

```
function CreateAccount() {
  CallPHP('php/getplayers.php', function(data) {
    var player  = undefined;
    var players = $.parseJSON(data) 
    for (i in players) {
      if (players[i].name == name) {
        player = players[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (player == undefined) {
      alert('Player account, "' + name + '" does not exist!');
    } else {
      alert('Player account, "' + name + '" already exists!');
    }
  });
}
```

Name is a global variable.

Unless I have  php script name and the success handler hardcoded as shown below it always ends up in the error handler and gets "Not connected. Verify Network.

What am I doing incorrectly?!

```
$.ajax({
    type:       "GET",
    url:       'php/geocache.php',
    data_type: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      var player  = undefined;
      var players = $.parseJSON(data) 
      for (i in players) {
        if (players[i].name == name) {
          player = players[i];
          break;
        }
      }
      if (player == undefined) {
        alert('Player account, "' + name + '" does not exist!');
      } else {
        alert('Player account, "' + name + '" already exists!');
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      var msg = '';
      if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
          msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
          msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
          msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
      } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
          msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
      } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
          msg = 'Time out error.';
      } else if (exception === 'abort') {
          msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
      } else {
          msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
      }
      alert(msg);
    },
});
```

Comment: The problem I see is the fact you are parsing data that is already json. `var players = $.parseJSON(data) `  should not be there, `data` should already be parsed by jQuery.

Comment: Also `data_type` isn't an option.  `dataType` is.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Why do you use loop in js script to check existing user? it's not better to check, if the player exists inside of php?